# How to load geojson vector tiles from mapbox id?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, mapbox, vector-tiles

I have some data hosted on [mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/) and I'm trying to load it as tiled geojson into Leaflet from its mapbox id (I just want to get plain geojson, I'm not trying to render it). How can I achieved that?

I tried this snippet:

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'myAccessToken';

var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer('myDataId');
```

but it doesn't work, I get the following error:

```
" could not load features at http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/"myDataId"/features.json?access_token="myAccessToken" "
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also haven't been able to get `L.mapbox.featureLayer()` to load vectors I've uploaded to MapBox.  Vector Tile source `.mbtiles` files are no longer `.geojsons` but have been converted into a bunch of tiled `.svgs` combined into one `.mbtiles` file, so I'm not sure if mapbox.js has the ability to render vector `.mbtiles` the same was it renders hosted `.geojson` files.

If you want to render the vector tileset on your map, try styling it in Mapbox Studio and uploading the style project to MapBox ([docs](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio/style-manual/)).

**EDIT**

OK, so looks like there are two different ways to import vector data into mapbox:

1. as a `.geojson` within the [MapBox Editor](https://www.mapbox.com/editor/).

[image]

2. as a vector `.mbtiles` set, uploaded via MapBox Studio or from the [MapBox Uploads page](https://www.mapbox.com/uploads/).

Data uploaded via the first method can be loaded onto a map with `L.mapbox.featureLayer`.  Data uploaded via the second method (tiled) must be first given a style in MapBox Studio (see link above) *or* rendered in a mapbox-gl map.

In summary: it is not possible to access the geojson data of a vector tiles source.

Comment: You're right, it works with the mapbox editor. I don't find a way to import my data in the editor directly from mapbox though.

Comment: coincidentally, mapbox [just blogged](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/choosing-the-right-tool/) about the difference between MapBox Studio and the MapBox Editor.

Answer (score 1):

what about

```
 L.mapbox.featureLayer('your_id').addTo(map);
```

Just tested it again and it works fine. Have you added these two lines with the up to date API and CSS?

```
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.5/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.5/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
```

[image]

Comment: It's nearly the same answer as Klaser. I still have the same error with this : /

Comment: The difference is the addtoMap method, so you add the layer to your map before you load the content.works fine here.perhaps post a bit more of your code to get an idea where's the problem

Comment: Could you give me the link to the fiddle please? I'll try to reproduce it with my id.

Comment: i just replaced my id/token with substitutes so you can fill in your id/token: http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/uh6ub3tf/

Comment: ok, it doesn't work for me. I only get the background tiles. I guess it's a problem with my data format but I don't know how to check that.
I made my data available to public api: yowza.14a37d8d

Comment: @Thomas How did you upload your data to mapbox?  Via MapBox Studio, or via the in-site upload button, or did you create the features as within a mapbox project?

Comment: I created them within a mapbox project. Which kind of data did you upload?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a MapBox-User, but the syntax to get the feature layer seems to be a bit different: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v1.6.1/l-mapbox-featurelayer/

Try this:

```
var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer()

// loads markers from the map `examples.map-0l53fhk2` on Mapbox,
// if that map has markers
featureLayer.loadID('examples.map-0l53fhk2');
```

Comment: I think that my syntax works in the [last version of the api](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.1.5/l-mapbox-featurelayer/#section-l-mapbox-featurelayer).

**L.mapbox.featureLayer(id|url|geojson, options)**

I tried your syntax but my error is still the same.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. I missinterpreted the doc earlier and I don't see why `var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer('map-id')` isn't working. Sorry I can't be of better help. Have you double-checked the map ID in your code? Has it worked in different contexts?

Comment: The map ID is good and I can load my data in mabox studio.