# mapbox overlay data

Tags: geojson, mapbox

I have loaded my geojson into Mapbox Studio sources and then uploaded it to Mapbox. Now I see my upload under my **Data** tab on mapbox.com.

How do I overlay that Data on my map using the Mapbox Javascript library.

These are the two versions I have tried ....

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = '<my-key>';

var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets')
.setView([35.2269, -80.8433], 12);    

var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer('mycrazydog.hz88h0k9')
.setZIndex(100)
.addTo(map);
```

AND

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = '<my-key>';

var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets')
.setView([35.2269, -80.8433], 12);    

var myTileLayer = L.mapbox.tileLayer('mycrazydog.hz88h0k9')
.setZIndex(100)
.addTo(map);
```

I have also tried to import the geojson directly into a mapbox.com **Project**, but it has too many features and crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to style your data in MapBox Studio as a **Style Project**, rather than pulling it into mapbox.js.

`L.mapbox.featureLayer('mycrazydog.hz88h0k9')` is for loading data uploaded in the [mapbox editor](https://www.mapbox.com/guides/editor/), which is a different workflow entirely from MapBox Studio **Source Projects**.

The distinction between the two is not as straightforward as it could be:

- use MapBox Studio **Source Projects** and **Style Projects** to create vector tilesets
- use the MapBox Editor (under the **Project** tab on MapBox.com) to add vector data on top of tilesets (though it sounds like in your case your geojson is too large to upload to the MapBox Editor.

It sounds like in your case--where the data is too large to host on the MapBox Editor--you need to create a **Style Project**.  Checkout the **Getting Started** and **Map Design** Guides on [this page](https://www.mapbox.com/guides/).

*update*

So, assuming you create a new **Style Project**, add the style project to your map as a `tileLayer`, rather than `featureLayer`.  Something like:

```
// if your style project layer has a transparent background and should be overlayed over the mapbox-streets baselayer
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets')
            .setView([35.2269, -80.8433], 12);

var tileLayer = L.mapbox.tileLayer('<mapbox_styleproject_id>')
                     .setZIndex(100)
                     .addTo(map);


//or, shortened to
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets', {
  layers: L.mapbox.tileLayer('<mapbox_styleproject_id>'),
  center: [35.2269, -80.8433],
  zoom: 12
});
```

Also see [this GIS.StackExchange post on vector tiles and geojsons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131829/how-to-load-geojson-vector-tiles-from-mapbox-id/)

Comment: OK, so then I style it using Mapbox Studio and upload that to the **Style** section of mapbox.com. Then do I use the **map id** from the **Style** section in my javascript? (ex. var myTileLayer = L.mapbox.tileLayer('<map-id-style>')

Do I then have to reference both the map-id from the **Data** section and the map-id from the **Style** section? ... How would that look?

Any chance you could please provide a quick example?

Comment: Exactly, reference the id of the style project.  No need to reference the id of the data project anywhere in your js code.  I'll update my answer with a quick description.

Comment: Also, check out mapbox-gl for a more advanced, still-very-much beta method of styling MapBox Studio Source Project vector tilesets: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/ .Rather than styling the vector tileset w/i MapBox Studio as a Style Project and serving it to your site, you pass just the vector tileset and style it w/i the browser using a new set of json-based style definitions.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my questions. This has been incredibly helpful!